# vim - add highlight properties and keep existing untouched

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I'd like to add highlighting properties to certain syntax groups, but whenever I add/replace a certain attribute, the rest seem to be overwritten too.

Example:

```
highlight default rubyConditional  cterm=italic
```

In this case, I want ruby conditionals to keep their original colour, and **add** the *italic* decoration to them. Alas, the above line seems to reset the `rubyConditional` group.

Is there a way in vim to keep the remaining attributes untouched, and just add/edit the declared attribute?

Comment: Are you sure you ran `highlight default`, not just `highlight`? I can explain the behaviour in the latter case, but not the former.